# ¿Por qué mi código no detecta los asteriscos escapados?

Tags: javascript, regex, bootstrap-tags-input

Estoy tratando de hacer una lista de etiquetas que son elementos posibles de una expresión regular y ponerles su tooltip, pero para el caso del `\*` no me está funcionando, pues me lo reconoce como `caracter punto`, en vez de `caracter asterisco`. ¿Qué habrá podido salir mal en el código?

```js
var predefined_list = [/^\\d$/, /^\d+$/, /^\*$/, /^\\*$/, /^\+$/, /^\.$/, /^\\.$/];
var descriptions = ["un dígito", "numero literal", "cualquier cantidad de veces", "caracter asterisco", "1 o más veces", "cualqueir caracter", "caracter punto"];

var lastAddedElement = null;

$("input").tagsinput({
  allowDuplicates: true,
  confirmKeys: [13, 32],
  trimValue: true,

});

$("#category-input").on("beforeItemAdd", function(event) {
  var item = event.item;
  for (var validElement of predefined_list) {
    if (validElement.test(item)) {
      lastAddedElement = item;
      return;
    }
  }
  event.cancel = true;
  lastAddedElement = null;
});

$("#category-input").on("itemAdded", function(event) {
  // console.log("item added : " + event.item);

  for (var [index, validElement] of predefined_list.entries()) {
    if (validElement.test(event.item)) {
      console.log(`${validElement.toString()} at index ${index}=> ${descriptions[index]}`);
      console.log(`validElement.toString():${validElement.toString()}`)
      console.log(`event.item.toString():${event.item.toString()}`);
      console.log(`lastAddedElement:${lastAddedElement.toString().replace('\\','\\\\')}`)
      $(`.label-info:contains(${lastAddedElement.toString().replace('\\','\\\\')})`).last().attr("title", descriptions[index] || "ola k ace");
      break;
    }
  }


});
```

```css
.tag {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.label-info {
  background-color: rgb(134, 92, 222);
}

.label {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  padding: 0.2em 0.6em 0.3em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="oppningarTd">
      <input id="category-input" type="text" class="oppningar" multiple="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es la expresión regular para 'caracter punto' `/^\\*$/`, te faltó un `\` más para que interprete el asterisco como caracter normal, no como parte de la expresión, tal como está significa "hacer match con un slash cualquier cantidad de veces.

```js
var predefined_list = [/^\\d$/, /^\d+$/, /^\*$/, /^\\\*$/, /^\+$/, /^\.$/, /^\\.$/];
var descriptions = ["un dígito", "numero literal", "cualquier cantidad de veces", "caracter asterisco", "1 o más veces", "cualqueir caracter", "caracter punto"];

var lastAddedElement = null;

$("input").tagsinput({
  allowDuplicates: true,
  confirmKeys: [13, 32],
  trimValue: true,

});

$("#category-input").on("beforeItemAdd", function(event) {
  var item = event.item;
  for (var validElement of predefined_list) {
    if (validElement.test(item)) {
      lastAddedElement = item;
      return;
    }
  }
  event.cancel = true;
  lastAddedElement = null;
});

$("#category-input").on("itemAdded", function(event) {
  // console.log("item added : " + event.item);

  for (var [index, validElement] of predefined_list.entries()) {
    if (validElement.test(event.item)) {
      console.log(`${validElement.toString()} at index ${index}=> ${descriptions[index]}`);
      console.log(`validElement.toString():${validElement.toString()}`)
      console.log(`event.item.toString():${event.item.toString()}`);
      console.log(`lastAddedElement:${lastAddedElement.toString().replace('\\','\\\\')}`)
      $(`.label-info:contains(${lastAddedElement.toString().replace('\\','\\\\')})`).last().attr("title", descriptions[index] || "ola k ace");
      break;
    }
  }


});
```

```css
.tag {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.label-info {
  background-color: rgb(134, 92, 222);
}

.label {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  padding: 0.2em 0.6em 0.3em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="oppningarTd">
      <input id="category-input" type="text" class="oppningar" multiple="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a la expresión regular estas solicitando que la cadena caracteres comience con el carácter especificado y termine con el.

Te recomiendo revisar tus expresiones regulares en la pagina: https://regexr.com/

Por ejemplo, si agregar en la expresión regular lo siguiente `/^\\*$/` y en la caja de texto solo escribes `*` entonces notaras que existe un match entre tu expresión y el texto, sin embargo, si agregar cualquier texto antes o después del asterisco entonces no sera valido debido a tu regla `^` (inicia con) y la que especifica `$` (termina con).

En lo que respecta a tu lógica de evaluación esta bien si solo quieres detectar cadena de caracteres que sean validas con tus expresiones regulares.

Nota: Podrías agregar más casos de prueba para ayudar mejor.
Nota2: En la expresión `/^\\*$/` no habrás querido decir `/^\*$/`.

Comment: Lo que "quise decir" es lo que Diego puso, el forzar inicio y término de cadena son muy necesarios

Comment: Ah bien, de todas formas la página que agregar sirve mucho para probar expresiones regulares y probablemente sea de ayuda para probar ese tipo de casos, además tiene documentación en el mismo sitio web donde puedes confirmar varias combinaciones. Saludos!